# Model Yii2 with ReflectionClass not working

Tags: php, yii2

I have code - working correct (I do not have to inculde class ReflectionClass):

```
class Test
{
    const TYPE_ONE = "Number one";
    const TYPE_TWO = "Number two";

    static function getConstants() { 

        $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        return $oClass->getConstants();
    }
}

   foreach (Test::getConstants() as $kay => $val):
   echo "$kay -- $val <br/>";
   endforeach;
```

But, when i try use ReflectionClass in code Yii2 i gets the message

```
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'common\models\ReflectionClass' not found
```

If there are any Reflection classes in the framework or a way to declare ReflectionClass in Yii2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because yii2 use *namespaces*, when you call `new ReflectionClass()` php looking for this class in the namespace that you declare at the beginnig of a file, in your case its `namespace common\models;` To load php's classes you need to prepend their names with *\*. So to instantiate *ReflectionClass* you need to write `new \ReflectionClass(__CLASS__)`. More in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)